# Error 500 en Heroku: template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, spring-tool-suite

Tengo este proyecto

```java
@GetMapping(value = { "/cliente/listar", "cliente" })
public String listar(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("titulo", "Lista de Clientes");
    model.addAttribute("clientes", clienteService.findAll());
    return "/cliente/NewFile";
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estando en el navegador, cuando trato de ingresar a la ruta del endpoint me sale el siguiente error cuando despliego mi proyecto spring:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Apr 24 00:25:57 UTC 2021 There was an unexpected error
> (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

Y esto es lo que aparece en los logs de Heroku:

> 2021-04-24T00:48:27.706944+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/cliente/listar" host=pruebafinalassasas.herokuapp.com
> request_id=836c140d-71a0-40a1-8183-5f564e9d3dd0 fwd="89.40.206.190"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=482
> protocol=https 2021-04-24T00:48:39.251703+00:00 heroku[router]:
> at=info method=GET path="/cliente/listar"
> host=pruebafinalassasas.herokuapp.com
> request_id=ba740297-c7d7-4444-9df5-77bf32231537 fwd="89.40.206.190"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=482
> protocol=https 2021-04-24T00:48:39.245896+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-04-24
> 00:48:39.245 ERROR 4 --- [io-24752-exec-1]
> org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             :
> [THYMELEAF][http-nio-24752-exec-1] Exception processing template
> "/cliente/NewFile": Error resolving template [/cliente/NewFile],
> template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the
> configured Template Resolvers 2021-04-24T00:48:39.245906+00:00
> app[web.1]:  2021-04-24T00:48:39.245917+00:00 app[web.1]:
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
> template [/cliente/NewFile], template might not exist or might not be
> accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
> 2021-04-24T00:48:39.245920+00:00 app[web.1]:  at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> 2021-04-24T00:48:39.245921+00:00 app[web.1]:  at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.12.RELEASE]

Aclaro que ejecutandolo local funciona sin problemas pero cuando despliego en heroku me arroja esto que comento.

Comment: Que más te aparece en tu log?

Comment: cuando despliego sale que esta bien, pero esta fallando cuando trato de ingresar a la ruta del controlador https://pruebafinalassasas.herokuapp.com/cliente/listar este es el proyecto desplegado

Comment: En la pagina de Heroku, hay un apartado donde esta la consola, la cual te da mostrando todos los errores que vas teniendo. Puedes agregar esa info a tu pregunta.

Comment: ya puse el logs

Comment: Localmente te anda porque no es codigo empaquetado lo que estas ejecutando a menos que hayas hecho tus pruebas locales ejecutando directamente del jar o war. Fijate que tu archivo **NewFile.html** esta en los recursos por lo que al empaquetarlo en el jar ya va a cambiar la forma de consumirlo. No estoy del todo seguro que sea esto lo que a heroku no le guste pero prueba devolver el archivo como `return Class.getResource("/cliente/NewFile");` . Haz un build del código y pruebalo localmente desde el .jar y si anda prueba desde Heroku para descartar si es esto o no

Comment: encontré el error y era en   return "/cliente/NewFile"; asi funciona bien en local pero en heroku no, asi funciona en heroku y local return "cliente/NewFile";  y pensar que me pase 2 dias en esto, saludos

Comment: @Adrian era lo que te comentaba? ya que encontraste el error, podrías responder a tu pregunta marcando cuál era la solución?

Answer (score 0):

la error era que a la hora de mapear lo que retornaba era  return "/cliente/NewFile"; cosa que funcionaba bien en local pero no funcionaba en heroku, la solución fue  return "cliente/NewFile"; sin la primera raya inclinada, en resumen el error era por poner la raya inclinada al inicio de la ruta